# Slow storage spaces direct S2D setup

Tags: windows-server-2016, storage-spaces

I have two Dell R710's with 8 Cores 64+ GB RAM, Flashed Dell H200 with 9211 IT mode, 4 teamed gbe nics, Server 2016
One server has:
2 x 480 GB SSD's
3X 2TB HDD
1x 3 TB HDD
The other
2 x 240 GB SSD
4 x 2 TB HDD

I have an external server with 2012 R2 SS with just 2x4TB Drives, and another with 6+ HDD (no SSDs).

Transfers from the external servers to each other top out the 1GB connections they have, 100MB/s file transfers. From those to my S2D cluster I top out around 14MB/s or so.

I can't find anything to help me diagnose what is soooo slow. Column count 4, 4k, Mirrored, Cluster validion report check, What can i do to figure out why this is soo slow? I know 10Gbe with RDMA is 'recommended' but I'm not sure why it is this bad really. This was going to be my new cluster @ home but Its not really usable like this. Help? Desperate.....

Also windows VM shows 500ms average response time from the disk. Yikes

Answer (score 6):

You really need RDMA-capable 10 GbE for your backbone connectivity. 4x1GbE is simply not enough for Storage Spaces Direct. Get Mellanox ConnectX3 or similar cards, you can get used/refurb cheap from eBay.

P.S. S2D doesn't shine on a two-node config...

Comment: I may try the 10GBe cards. Trying to pinpoint and prove that its networking that is holding me back. I just can't find evidence of it.

Answer (score 6):

> I may try the 10GBe cards. Trying to pinpoint and prove that its networking that is holding me back. I just can't find evidence of it.

RDMA-capable 10GbE NICs is kinda a requirement for S2D. Also, just want to add that @BaronSamedi1958 is right about "S2D doesn't shine on a two-node config..." thereby I would recommend taking a look at SDS solutions that were designed for 2 nodes. First, that comes to my mind is HPE VSA they can create 2 node HA with cloud witness, either you can give a shot to StarWind VSAN they are using 2 nodes only, with no witness-node as the requirement.